# (int) in MainActivity cannot be applied

Tags: java, android

I build an app, and I try of call a method in another, but it show me this error :

> (int) in MainActivity cannot be applied

how can I fix this?

```
public void Method1 () {
    alet(); //here it show the error
}

public void alet (int position) {
      rutaGE = getemployeeName(position);
      jornadaGE = getmailid(position);

}
```

and I can't delete `int position`, because I need I get `rutaGE` and `JornadaGE` in another method.

Comment: The function takes a parameter (an integer).  You aren't passing it one.  You need to.

Comment: `alet();` expects a int that you are not passing to the method

Comment: is there any other method implementation for just alet();

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to add int parameter to the alet() method.

```
public void Method1 () {
    int myPosition = 4;
    alet(myPosition);
    }

public void alet (int position) {
      rutaGE = getemployeeName(position);
      jornadaGE = getmailid(position);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method need an `int position` so you have to pass something to `alet`, for example `alet(0)`